# Can I decrease clock speed like this?

Tags: system-verilog, state-machine

```
logic [28:0] count;
always@ (posedge clk)

if (reset)
    state<= S0;
else
begin
    count=count+1;
    case(speed)
        2'b00: if(count[23]) state<=nextstate;
        2'b01: if(count[24]) state<=nextstate;
        2'b10: if(count[25]) state<=nextstate;            
        2'b11: if(count[26]) state<=nextstate;
        default: state<=nextstate;

    endcase
end
```

Speed is an input, I tried to decrease the clock speed with this in my state register, I get no error at synthesis but I get wrong outputs. Outputs slows down when I change the speed however all of my leds light up in low voltage and I get back to the same state, stucked.

Comment: Not understood, what you want to do here? Can you please post your full code here?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by setting count 0 before each nextstate